# iOS 8 - Keyboard changes colour if you press Home button on iPad and come back in

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, keyboard, uikit

To replicate:

1. Create a blank single-view project
2. Drag a TextField on to the canvas
3. Set the TextField keyboardAppearance to Dark
4. Run the app on iPad (device or simulator)
5. Touch the TextField to bring up the keyboard (it is dark)
6. Press Home, then come back into the app
7. Notice the keyboard changes colour (to white).

Presumably the keyboard colour changes to match the background. However in this case some of the keys remain dark, so this seems like a bug in iOS (see attached screenshot).

Anyone care to shed any light on this? We're using a workaround which involves hiding the keyboard and re-showing it, but this isn't ideal.

[image]

Comment: Instead of hiding and showing the keyboard again, try `[textField reloadInputViews]` on `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

This code can close the keyboard when Home button is pressed and bring it back when the app re-starts. You need to set UITextFields **delegate** to the view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

private var _textField: UITextField!
private var _isFirstResponder: Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "didBecomeActiveNotification:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "willResignActiveNotification:", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func didBecomeActiveNotification(nofication: NSNotification) {
    if _isFirstResponder? == true {
        _textField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func willResignActiveNotification(nofication: NSNotification) {
    if _textField?.isFirstResponder() == true {
        _isFirstResponder = true
        _textField?.resignFirstResponder()
    } else {
        _isFirstResponder = false
    }
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    _textField = textField
    return true
}

}
```